# Effect of placement of deference operator vs whitespace in C

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [what is the difference between “int  *i” and “int* i”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846930/what-is-the-difference-between-int-i-and-int-i)
>   [what is the difference between const int*,  const int * const, int const *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const)

What is the difference between

```
char* getInput();
```

and

```
char *getInput();
```

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846930/what-is-the-difference-between-int-i-and-int-i/1846942#1846942

Comment: None. And they are not function pointers.

Comment: The difference is personal preference.

Answer (score 9):

As far as the C compiler is concerned, there is no difference.

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference.

```
int* a;
int *b;
int * c;
```

There is no different between a, b or c there either. They're both pointers. It's just you can put as many spaces in as you like.

*However*, there is a difference between these:

```
int* a, a1, a2;
int *b, b1, b2;
int *c, *c1, *c2;
```

only on line C have you declared 3 pointers-to-ints. A and B both have one pointer-to-int and two ints.

Answer (score 3):

No difference it all. Note that all the following declarations are the same:

- `char*getInput();`
- `char* getInput();`
- `char *getInput();`
- `char * getInput();`
- `char* getInput ();`
- `char *getInput ();`
- `char * getInput ();`
- `char* getInput ( );`
- `char *getInput ( );`
- `char * getInput ( );`
- `char* getInput ( ) ;`
- `char *getInput ( ) ;`
- `char * getInput ( ) ;`

All of them let the compiler know there is a function named `getInput` that returns a `char *` and gets passed a specific, but unspecified, number of arguments of specific, but unspecified, types.

---

*Edit*

The space character in source files is mostly ignored and redundant.

```
for (n = 0; n < 1000; n++) { /* ... */ }
for(n=0;n<1000;n++){/*...*/}
```

It only matters inside strings and when it is needed to separate tokens that can't be separated by other means.

```
return 9; /* statement that returns from a function */
return9;  /* statement that evaluates a variable */
```

Answer (score 2):

The location of the space.

Answer (score 2):

To the compiler, there is no difference.

To my brain, the first form is preferred because it shows that the function returns a pointer-to-char (and not a char) more clearly.  Of course, that is strictly IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

None from a semantical & syntactical point of view.

Comment: None from syntactical point of view either.

Answer (score 1):

No difference at all in terms of meaning. In fact, none even in terms of syntax. As long as the whitespace is *somewhere*, there's no problem. Both compile to precisely the same code.

It is often a matter of preference which is used. The traditional C coders generally prefer the second, as it is more indicative that the type is still `char`, regardless of the fact it's a pointer. Many C++ coders, as I believe Bjarne Stroustrup himself has pointed out, prefer the `char*` syntax because it is considered more in the OOP style. I personally prefer this one too, as it signifies that the variable is a *char pointer*.

Edit: Can't find where he actually wrote that, but you can see quite plainly in his [BC++ Style and Technique FAQ](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html) guide that he prefers the `char*` style syntax.

Comment: But when you declare an array of char, you don't write `char[N] a;`, do you?  The "pointer-ness" of a variable is part of the declarator: it's a happy accident that `*` can be written to appear as though it's part of the type specifier, but it doesn't accurately reflect the declaration syntax.

Answer (score 0):

you mean char (*getInput)();
Without the brackets you'd have a function that returned a pointer to a char. With brackets getInput is a pointer to function which returns char.

Answer (score -1):

I know i am answering what all have said...Just want to add a few more things :

What u possibly wanted to ask might be : 
char* getInput();
char (*getInput)();

Over here the first one represents : getInput is a function which returns pointer to a char.
second is : getInput is a pointer to a function which returns a char.

In case of complicated declarations always remember!!! START READING FROM INSIDE THE BRACKETS

Consider this : char* (*getInput)();
Here, getInput is a pointer to a function which returns a pointer to a char.