# Whats the difference between float* varname and float *varname in classic c

Tags: c, syntax

What's the difference between float* varname and float *varname in classic C?

Comment: There is no difference, the compiler is happy either way.  'C' programmers tend to favor the space after the type name, causes less confusion when you declare more than one variable.  This *has* to be dupe.

Comment: You've opened up a religious can of worms. :)  I'm surprised that most of the answers so far are mild-mannered.

Comment: Wasn't this asked yesterday but with `int` being the type instead? And yesterday's question was a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate?

Comment: show me the dupe please i didn't find it

Comment: @James and @Peanut: It's true that it has been asked before. But it is very difficult to search for them, unless you happen to guess the variable names that were used in the examples. However here's one from last week: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065232/. You can find the other duplicates by scraping recursively from that post!

Comment: @Daniel thanks I didn't try searching on other types, just checked the context search list that came up and didn't see anything

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Formatting. That's it. They mean the same thing.

Where you put the space (or if you even have one, really) is a matter of preference. Some prefer the * next to the varname so that you don't get confused by something like:

```
float* a, b;
```

(here, only a is a pointer, b is not)

Others argue that they never declare multiple variables at once, so they prefer the * next to float, since it's part of the type.

Comment: One wonders how those who put the `*` next to `float` because "it's part of the type" ever manage to declare arrays.

Comment: You still can't put the `[N]` next to the rest of the type, though.

Comment: @caf: That's why I find the whole "it describes the type" argument to be specious, because it's inconsistent with *every other type*; every time I see something like `int* a[10];` or `double* foo();` it just screams confused thinking to me.

Comment: @caf: Sure you can. If you say `template <typename T> struct identity { typedef T type; };` then you can say `identity<int[10]>::type numbers;` which puts the `[N]` part right next to the type.

Comment: @FredOverflow: That's an egregious syntax error in C, and this question is specifically about "classic C".

Comment: @caf: Whoops, sorry, I was still in C++ mode :)

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference. The whitespace is completely ignored.

However note that the following can be misleading:

```
float* var1, var2;
```

Casual examination of the above would lead you to think that both var1 and var2 are pointers to a float. However you'd be wrong, because this declares var1 as a pointer to a float, but var2 would be a regular float.

Comment: It's an interesting thing that C considers the * to be associated more with the variable name than with the pointer-to type. Kind of makes you wish for the old Pascal colon as a disambiguation - separate the shared type from the names-with-modifiers list.

Comment: @Steve314 But think about what happens when you have `typedef int *foo_t;`, then `foo_t a, b, c;`.  At that point C "considers" the `*` to be associated with the type.  (Although I would argue that the C language doesn't really "consider" anything...)

Answer (score 4):

The latter is more explicit in that it shows that you are creating a variable which is a pointer to a float, instead of creating a variable that is a float pointer. This becomes important in constructs such as:

```
float *foo, bar;
```

foo is a pointer to a float, but bar is just a float.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly, it is a matter of coding style. However, most C programmers prefer to use the second option: `float *var;` as it is closer to how the language syntax binds the `*` asterisk: the `*` is bound to the declarator, not the specifier of type.

In other words, C programmers translate `float *var` as `*var` is of type of float. but not `var` is of type of `float*`.

There is more elaborate explanation in Wikipedia article [C variable types and declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_variable_types_and_declarations#Pointer_types)

Also, you may find the question [C Pointer Syntax: Style poll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663071/c-pointer-syntax-style-poll) interesing.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, it makes no difference - matter of style. Note that in C++ it's customary to write:

```
type* var;
```

Because the pointer is part of the type - at least this true for custom types. But by extension for built-in types too. So it makes some sense in C to do the same to be consistent. Personally I find it more intuitive to have pointer part of the type.

Answer (score 0):

There is effectively no difference; the declaration is parsed *as though* it were written `float (*varname);`.

In both C and C++, declarations are centered around *expressions*, not objects; basically, the form of the declaration should match the form of the expression in executable code (IOW, declaration mimics use).  For example, if you have a pointer to an integer named `p` and you want to access that integer *value* that `p` points to, you dereference the pointer like so:

```
x = *p;
```

The type of the *expression* `*p` is int; thus, the declaration should look like

```
int *p;
```

Similarly, if you have an array of int named `arr` and you want to access the integer value at a specific element `i`, you would write

```
x = a[i];
```

The type of the *expression* `a[i]` is int; thus, the declaration should look like

```
int a[N];
```

In the examples above, `*p` and `a[N]` are called *declarators*; declarators introduce the name of the object being declared along with *additional type information not provided in the type specifier*.  The int-ness of both `p` and `a` are provided by the type specifier `int`, but the pointer-ness of `p` and the array-ness of `a` are provided by their respective *declarators*.

This is an important point, and something that needs to be stressed; the `*` of both `int *p;` and `int* p;` is bound to the *declarator*, not the type specifier, regardless of whitespace.  The fact that you can write it either way is an accident of C (and C++) syntax, and as a result there's a school of thought that pointer variables should be declared as `T* p;` as opposed to `T *p;`, since the *type* of `p` is "pointer to T".  My problem is that reasoning *only* works for simple pointer types; we cannot treat array or function types the same way.  For example, we cannot write `int[N] arr;`, even though the *type* of `arr` is "N-element array of int".  It really falls down when we get into declaring pointers to arrays, or pointers to functions, or combinations of such.  For example:

```
int *(*(*(*farr)())[N])();
```

The *type* of `farr` is "pointer to a function returning a pointer to an N-element array of pointers to functions returning pointers to int".  Everything other than the "int" is part of the declarator; writing `int* (*(*(*farr)())[N])();` or even `int*(*(*(* farr)())[N])();` would just be ... silly.

I believe that insisting on writing `T* p;` for pointer declarations results in more confusion, not less.  Much as Stroustrup and legions of C++ programmers would like to pretend otherwise, declarations in C and C++ are centered around *expressions*, not objects.

Since I'm part of a larger team writing C++ code, I follow the agreed-upon coding guidelines which include declaring pointer and references as `T* p;` and `T& r;`, but it makes me grind my teeth every time I have to do it.